# Python: Dataframes FutureWarning: for list-likes to .loc or []

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains 4,000,000 records, I use it to apply rules and update a particular column with rule id

```
test_condition="(df['column_a']=='US' & df['column_b']=='GB')"
intermediate_df=df.loc[eval(test_condition),['column_a','column_b']]
intermediate_df.loc[:,'column_b']=str(variable1) + "-----" + str(variable2)
```

for the below line

```
intermediate_df=df.loc[eval(test_condition),['column_a','column_b']]
```

A warning message is popped

**FutureWarning: 
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.**

However, when i try to reindex() for example

```
intermediate_df=df.reindex([eval(test_condition),columns='column_a','column_b'])
```

I get completely different results (not same as loc)
Can someone suggest me how to modify from loc to reindex()

Comment: what is the result of `print(df.columns)` looks like either of `['column_a','column_b']` is not preent in your dataframe or may have some spaces

Comment: why are you using eval here? there is no purpose except to expose yourself to risk